# Oracle query to replace same character with different characters based on position

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string in Oracle DB in the format 'a|b|c' , '|' being the separator between characters. Want to write an SQL query to transform it into a string in the format 'a,b&c'. First occurrence of '|' to ',' 2nd occurrence to '&'.

If suppose the string comes in the format 'a|b' then output should be 'a&b'.

I'm using multiple regex_replace queries to achieve this right now.

```
 select REGEXP_REPLACE ('a|b|c', '[|]', ',', 1, 1)
    from dual
```

Is there any other solution using one single query?

Comment: Yes, use two replace commands. In Oracle, you cannot use  a conditional replacement pattern in REGEXP_REPLACE.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. But we can combine both replaces into 1 query. as in the below solution provided by MT0.

Comment: That is still using two REGEXP_REPLACE commands, as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Nested replaces (see line #6):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'a|b|c' from dual union all
  3     select 'a|b'   from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6    regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col, '\|', ',', 1, 1), '\|', '&', 2, 1) result
  7  from test;

COL   RESULT
----- --------------------
a|b|c a,b&c
a|b   a,b

SQL>
```

Comment: This might not work if string is 'a|b' - Expected o/p is 'a&b' or if string is 'a|b|c|d'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the last `|` in the list with `&` and all the preceding `|`s with `,` then you can use:

```sql
SELECT value,
       REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE( value, '\|([^|]*)$', '&\1' ),
         '|',
         ','
       ) AS replaced
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'A|B|C|D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A|B|C'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A|B'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A'       FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE | REPLACED |
| --- | --- |
| A|B|C|D | A,B,C&D |
| A|B|C | A,B&C |
| A|B | A&B |
| A | A |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZL80LR_z)